# Embed blogger in my website - auto height and scrolling

Tags: html, css, iframe, blogger, blogs

[there](http://matejp.jecool.net/blog.html) is my site.
I've embeded blogger into this site. How can I make parallel scroll and auto section resize (because of height of blog)?
Thanks, M

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer below and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
    /* Shows scrollbar always visible */
    #your-div-name {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: auto;
    }  
</style>
```